# Know the url of File being downloaded from App on Android phone

Tags: url

This is the situation: I have an app named "ABC" installed on my phone. and it has some media files which can be downloaded.
when I click on files shown in the app it starts downloading and I can see in the download manager app which comes by default in the phone.

I'm trying to know the download url of the file being downloaded, but I couldn't.

could any body please suggest the way to know download url, so that I can use IDM/uget in the system to download in faster way???

Comment: This is the situation: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to install a network packet sniffer app; there are some that do not require root, by acting like a VPN app.  You seem to be technically savvy since you mention `IDM` and `uget` so what you would also need besides the packet sniffer app is software to analyze the resulting capture.  Generally, once you capture the data you would transfer it to a PC then run a network capture protocol analyzer; such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) (available for Windows, OS X, and Unix) to analyze the traffic and you should be able to find the URL of the file.